# Is it possible to make an ios alarm app that you can't terminate manually?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Question (Straight to the point):

Is it possible to make an alarm app that you can terminate **ONLY** in the actual app by going through actions in the app?

ex) There was an alarm app that I had to shake to terminate, but I could easily turn it off by pressing home button, then double clicking the home button and terminate from 'task manager', or whatever it's called.
I do not want my app to die by these actions. I want it to come back from the dead, activating itself even if the user terminates it. (I have seen one app do this a year ago)

Longer explanation/blah blah:

I want to make an alarm app. Well, we have thousands of those on the app store. Therefore, I want to make mine that you have to solve calculations to turn off. Yes, I know this too is on the market.

So, the final product I want to make will have two key features:
1. Really hard problems. Not those lame 15+46, I mean differential equations that require pen and paper.
2. Can be turned off only by following instructions. Manually terminating will not work.

Comment: Public app: nope. Private app: more than likely.

Comment: you would need a webserver sending push notifications to reactivate the app, and even then i'm not sure its possible.

Comment: Edit: I digged up the app I downloaded a year ago. It's "Wake Up Pro Alarm", which revives itself even after termination. I could try contacting the devs to ask how they did it and how apple authorized them, but I doubt they will respond.

Comment: That app was updated fairly recently in August... I reckon they would respond :) Best of luck!